# Is $f$ and $g$ is Riemann-integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

let  $f : [0,1] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ and $g:[0,1] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be two  function  define by

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac {1}{n},\text{ if }x = \frac{1}{n},n \in \mathbb{N}\\
0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ and   $$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
n,\text{ if } x = \frac{1}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}  \\
0, \text{ otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Then    choose the correct option

$a)$ both $f$ and g are Riemann-integrable

$b)$ $f$ is Riemann-integrable but $g$ is not

$c)$ $g$ is  Riemann-integrable  but  $f$ is not

$d)$ neither $f$ nor $g$ is Riemann-integrable

i thinks option $d)$  will correct that  is   neither $f$ nor $g$ is Riemann-integrable because $f$ and  $g$ are not  continuous.

Is its  True ??

Comment: Is it true that Riemann integrable functions must be continuous?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path  ya  i missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is the correct answer. $g$ is not even a bounded function so it is not a Riemann integrable. $f$ is Riemann integrable because it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: one more  doubts    @Kavi sir   $g(x)$  has   countable point  of  discontinuity   i mean it  can  be  reimann integrable ??

Comment: Yes, any bounded function with only countable number of discontinuities is Riemann integrable.

Comment: okkss  thanks u sir i gots its